# Python 3 relative import full module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, import

I'm trying to make some code Python 3 compatible. To my understanding, in Python 3, importing a module from the same package must be relative. So if this is the directory structure:

```
/package
    /modA
    /modB
```

there's a lot of existing code that looks like this (in modA):

```
import modB
modB.some_function()
```

Is there a way to change the imports so I can keep calling the methods/properties the same way?

I know you can do this:

```
from .modB import some_function
some_function()
```

But I'd like to avoid changing all the calls if possible. When I call it like so:

```
import .modB
```

it gives an error

Answer (score 2):

The syntax to relative-import a module `modB` from the same package would be

```
from . import modB
```

Comment: @GoranB. I'll bite, I downvoted you for a couple reasons: 1. why rename `importlib` to `implib`? ok you save 3 characters of typing but at what readability cost? 2. Using `importlib` when there's a **builtin syntax exactly for this** is just wrong 3. Importing modules with `importlib` can throw off static analysis tools which can no longer follow the import.  So no, it's not a "perfectly acceptable answer", it's bad advice.

Comment: so why didn't you just put a better answer rather than looking to tear someone down?  and although it is not an optimal answer it certainly is not bad advice as you put it, it's your opinion ... anyway, guys like you are dime a dozen on SO

Comment: @GoranB. there was already a better answer, this one, I upvoted it.  I'm not looking to put people down but if you don't post the correct answer I'm going to click the "This answer is not useful" button.

Comment: according to http://python-future.org/compatible_idioms.html#imports-relative-to-a-package it should work for py2 and py3, but it doesn't to me

Comment: @RodrigoE.Principe: Then you've probably done something to screw up your package structure, perhaps by running a package submodule as if it were a script. It's hard to tell from here.

Comment: @user2357112 thank you for your concern, it turned out I was doing a circular importing and the traceback pointed to the relative import, which was not the problem

Answer (score 0):

This extends the answer of @user2357112

In order to work in both python2 and python3 you have to:

Structure:

```
/package
    __init__.py
    modA.py
    modB.py
```

content of `__init__.py`

```
from . import modA, modB
```

content of `modA.py`

```
# from . import modB  ## works in py3 but not in py2

def testA():
    """ call a function from modB """
    from . import modB
    modB.printB()

def printA():
    print('I am in modA')
```

content of `modB.py`

```
# from . import modA  ## works in py3 not in py2

def testB():
    """ call a function from modA """
    from . import modA
    modA.printA()

def printB():
    print('I am in modB')
```

Then you can do:

```
import package

package.modA.testA()
package.modB.testB()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use importlib

```
import importlib
```

and then

```
modB = importlib.import_module('package.modB')
```

... granted it's not optimal but still a working option if you're having persistent issues with relative path imports (never run into issues on POSIX and OSx, but on NT platform I have)